# Error: /path/to/library has no manifest, even though it does - Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, raspberry-pi, raspbian, swift-package-manager

I am developing library for SSD1306 (OLED screen driver) on iMac. In order to test it I have to run it on raspberry, which has connected OLED screen. So, I shared the folder through SMB to my raspberry pi zero. I have successfully mounted it at `/home/pi/SwiftOLED`. Now in order to test it I created project named test at `/home/pi/test`. It's manifest file:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "test",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(path: "/home/pi/SwiftOLED/"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/uraimo/SwiftyGPIO.git", .exact("1.1.3")),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "test",
            dependencies: ["SwiftyOLED", "SwiftyGPIO"]),
    ]
)
```

As you can see I am using [this way of defining a package dependency](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0201-package-manager-local-dependencies.md) to avoid having to commit, tag, push my library just to test if something works.

**Error**
Unfortunately, when I run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/test $ swift build
Updating https://github.com/uraimo/SwiftyGPIO.git
error: /home/pi/SwiftOLED has no manifest
```

I get this error, which would be reasonable only if I hadn't had a manifest file.

```swift
pi@raspberrypi:~/test $ cat /home/pi/SwiftOLED/Package.swift 
// swift-tools-version:5.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftyOLED",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SwiftyOLED",
            targets: ["SwiftyOLED"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/uraimo/SwiftyGPIO.git", .exact("1.1.3")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SwiftyOLED",
            dependencies: ["SwiftyGPIO"]),
    ]
)
```

And yes, the permissions seems to be ok, since during mounting a set the ownership of mounted files to pi

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/SwiftOLED $ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    0 Jun  8 02:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 pi pi 4096 Jun  9 00:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi 6148 Jun  8 02:13 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    0 Jun  8 22:09 .build
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    0 Jun  9 01:17 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi   38 Jun  8 02:13 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi  326 Jun  8 02:30 Package.resolved
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi  439 Jun  8 02:30 Package.swift
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi pi  167 Jun  8 02:29 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    0 Jun  8 02:09 Sources
```